# Можно ли использовать один и тот-же том/раздел для двух виртуальных серверов которые выполняют одну и ту же функцию?

Tags: сервер, сеть, клиент-сервер, виртуализация, виртуальная-машина

Есть один физический диск. Он разделен на виртуальные. Есть два виртуальных сервера. Заказчик требует чтобы второй виртуальный сервер при сбоях в первом подхватывал и работал в нормальном режиме продолжал работу. Но есть проблема - ограничение в памяти на физических жестких дисках. Есть идея взять один и тот же том на котором сидит 1ая виртуальная машина и вторую закрепить за тем же томом. Так чтобы они оба использовали одну и ту же операционную систему, одни и те-же файлы, и тд. и тп. Есть ли возможность реализовать подобную вещь. У кого есть какие идеи?